Нужно ли ставить запятую и тире в данном случае?
Но вдруг что-то мигнуло, — такого Тулло ещё не видел!

Нужны. И запятая и тире. Они выступают единым знаком при "переломе конструкции", что и наблюдается в нашем случае.

Запятая и тире ставятся для обозначения «перелома» первоначальной
конструкции, для указания, «с одной стороны, на расчлененность
предложения, а с другой — на то, что та его часть, которая следует за
этим знаком препинания, делает структурный поворот от предшествующей
части под некоторым, большим или меньшим углом.


ответы справочной службы вопрос № 305181
№ 305181
Зачем запятая в этом высказывании после слова "половцы"? Наша страна не раз проходила через серьёзные испытания: и печенеги её терзали, и половцы, – со всем справилась.
Ответ
Это тот редкий случай, когда запятая и тире ставятся как единый знак препинания для обозначения «перелома» конструкции. Последняя часть – это комментарий ко всей предыдущей части, представляющей собой сложное предложение.

Правильно:
Но вдруг что-то мигнуло, — такого Тулло ещё не видел!
Пояснение
Знак выбирается по правилам Розенталя § 45 и § 46
Тире ставится, если субъект которых назван в первой части, а предикат образует вторую часть. Например: Но вдруг что-то мигнуло (субъект суждения, предмет речи) — так обычно мигает сигнализация (предикат суждения, характеристика предмета).
Но в заданном предложении другие логические отношения, поэтому ставим запятую и тире. Отношения присоединительные с оттенком дополнительного пояснения (мигание воспринято как нечто необычное).
ПРАВИЛА
2. Запятая и тире ставятся между двумя частями бессоюзного 
сложного предложения, из которых вторая носит 
присоединительный характер с каким-либо дополнительным 
оттенком значения (пояснительным, временным, условно- 
следственным и др.); нередко эта часть начинается 
местоименными словами тот, так, такой и т. п.

8. Тире ставится перед местоименными словами так, такой, 
таков, начинающими собой присоединительное предложение, 
входящее в состав бессоюзного сложного предложения: Приказ 
есть приказ — так его воспитал фронт (Вор.); Кривые улицы, 
маленькие деревянные дома — такой была значительная часть 
Москвы в начале XX века. Идти вперёд или погибнуть — таков 
был выбор у партизанского отряда;
В этих предложениях выражены суждения, субъект которых 
назван в первой части, а предикат образует вторую часть. 
Если логические отношения между обеими частями носят другой 
характер, то между ними ставятся запятая и тире: Загрязнение 
окружающей среды угрожает жизни на Земле, — так дальше 
продолжаться не может (Газ.). 


О едином знаке
 Ты вновь и вновь найдешь в моих стихах
 Все, что во мне тебе принадлежало.
 Пускай земле достанется мой прах, —
 Ты, потеряв меня, утратишь мало.
             У. Шекспир, сонет 74


Единый знак отнюдь не редок в классической и современной художественной литературе, в том числе это касается формулировки:
Пункт 3. Запятая и тире ставятся для обозначения 
«перелома» первоначальной конструкции, для указания, «с 
одной стороны, на расчлененность предложения, а с другой 
— на то, что та его часть, которая следует за этим знаком 
препинания, делает структурный поворот от предшествующей 
части под некоторым, большим или меньшим, “углом”. 



Особенно часто "расчлененность со структурный поворотом" встречается в стихотворной речи (там повороты на каждом шагу).

Но в приведенном предложении нет речи о расчлененности —  анафорическое местоимение ТАКОГО отсылает читателя к первой части предложения, так что связь очевидна. Соответственно, решать задачу надо по способу, предложенному Розенталем в § 45, где сравниваются два знака (тире и единый знак) именно для указательных местоимений.

